# Netbean is taking too much time to send build on server

Tags: codenameone

i have two projects in netbean. first is created by visual and other one in manual mode.

But when i am sending to build server, visual mode project takes 1 minute and manual code taking much longer time and not able to send on server. I have been waited for 20 minutes long, after waited i have stop the sending build. Can you please tell me, what is the solution for it.

Comment: In manual code, i have written many packages and classes.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a lot of data in the manual mode one?

Its unrelated to the manual vs. GUI builder but rather to the size and possibly complexity.

Comment: Thanks Shai, i got the problem, Actually i am having some images, that is set to very low resolution mode, so i thought its very good for my project. but image size increased with two time or more. So taking time to upload there. After i set it to HD so compression is very high and image size become very low. Thanks!